# GKE Ingress's healthcheck is failing for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to deploy Wordpress (Docker image: wordpress:5.1.1) and use the native GKE Ingress. When the site is not installed yet, it redirects you from `/` to `/wp-admin/install.php` with the HTTP status code 301. The problem is that the default healthcheck is trying to reach the `/` path and expects to get 200, but it receives 301 instead and considers the service unhealthy.

Is there any other endpoint, which could be used for the healthchecks?
Or maybe some other elegant solution, which would not require a modification of the Wordpress's core files?

UPD: `/wp-admin/install.php` seems to work fine, but doesn't seem to be a good universal solution.

Comment: Could you please provide your Ingress configuration? Editing your question by adding  the 'ingress.yaml' would be best.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's really not about `GKE`. It's about healthchecks for Load Balancers, as you pointed out. Please see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/826719/how-to-create-a-url-in-a-wordpress-that-will-return-code-200).
You don't need to change WP code files in any case. It's in general a bad idea to change WP core files.

P.S. `wp-content` dir is not core files, just in case.